# Php simple html dom parser find string with any character

Tags: php, html, parsing

I have this html

```
<div class="price-box">

                <p class="old-price">
            <span class="price-label">This:</span>
            <span class="price" id="old-price-326">
                8,69 €                </span>
        </p>

                    <p class="special-price">
            <span class="price-label">This is:</span>
            <span class="price" id="product-price-326">
                1,99 €                </span> <span style="">/ 6.87 </span>
        </p>


    </div>
```

I'm need get "1,99 €", but the id 'product-price-326' is generating random numbers. How to find 'product-price-*'? I'm trying

```
foreach($preke->find('span[id="product-price-[0-9]"]') as $div)
```

and

```
foreach($preke->find('span[id="product-price-"]') as $div)
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try `$preke->find('span[id^="product-price-"]')`.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13525124/simple-html-dom-wildcard-in-attribute

Comment: it's working. Thanks D4V1D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As per my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31540319/php-simple-html-dom-parser-find-string-with-any-character#comment51039992_31540319), here's what you need to do:

```
foreach($preke->find('span[id^="product-price-"]')  as $div) {} // note the ^ before the =
```

[`^=` means *starts with*.](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_begin.asp)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what `$preke` is, but if it's a DOM selector that supports proper class selectors you can use

```
$preke->find('span[id^="product-price"]')
```

or

```
$preke->find('span[id*="product-price"]')
```

The `^=` tells it to look for elements that has an ID starting with "product-price" and the `*=` tells it to look for elements that has an ID that contains "product-price".

Answer (score 1):

Try Like This Might Be Works

```
foreach($preke->find('span[id^="product-price-"]')  as $div) { /* Code */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

why not to get it using `class`?

```
echo $preke->find('.special-price', 0)->find('.price', 0)->plaintext;
```

this will get you `1,99 €`

Comment: Thanks, it works too, but now i'm got: "This is: 1,99 € / 6.87"